# html onchange/onblur compatibility

Tags: html, compatibility, onchange, onblur

I am currently writing a web site which must be compatible with all browsers including IE back to version 6.

I was wondering about compatibility issues with these two events in particular:
I am using them with a `<input>` tag with `type='text'`.

- OnBlur
- OnChange

Searching has found mixed responses and an incomplete list.

Specifically, the question is:

- Are there any known issues with the above two events (could be expanded to other HTML events)?
- If so, what methods can be used to work around these issues?

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All browsers should support these events pretty decently if you're only using them in text boxes. If you check out the [QuirksMode  event compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html), you'll see that IE has some issues with the change event in radio buttons and check boxes.

If you're not very familiar with JavaScript events in browsers, you'll find that the event model is a mess thanks to the fact that IE decided to do things differently from the standard. To overcome this problem, [you should be using a JavaScript framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863603/when-should-i-use-a-javascript-framework-library) like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/), or [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted?csw=1). These frameworks smooth out the differences so you'll (almost) never have to deal with the differences & bugs in the different browsers. There is [a great article on CodingHorror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninjas/) explaining why you should consider using a JavaScript framework if you plan on using JavaScript in your site that you should read if you're curious as to *why* you should use a JavaScript framework.

Also, if you're unfamiliar with browser events entirely, make sure you understand [the difference between onchange and onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785099/what-is-the-difference-between-onblur-and-onchange-atrribute-in-html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are no more problem with these two specific events than with all events in Internet Explorer plus the usual weird quirks such as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925683).

The general solution to event-handling and MANY other problems is to use a Javascript framework whose developers have bled their own blood to save yours, papering over all IE (and a few other) weirdnesses, such as [dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/support/faq/what-browsers-does-dojo-support).  As the Dojo folks say on that page:

> The word "support" means something
>   very specific for Dojo and Dijit, in
>   that saying that Dojo Core and Dijit
>   support a browser means that 100% of
>   the available functionality works,
>   that accessibility is handled
>   correctly, and that all
>   internationalization and localization
>   is supported. This is a *very* high
>   bar, which also means that while we
>   may not saying that browsers like
>   Opera are "supported" for Dijit, it's
>   highly likely that it will all work
>   there too, but there may be some
>   caveat which we were not able to work
>   around (such as accessibility hook on
>   Opera).

The browsers they claim as "supported" at this very-high-bar level are (as of Dojo 1.3.2) IE 6 to 8, Safari 3.1 to 4, Firefox 2 to 3.5, Chrome 1 to 2 (core functionality, including event handling, also works on Opera, Konqueror, FF 1.5, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, try this:

```
$('input.text').click(function () {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $('input.text').blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
        }
    });
```

`$("input:text")` if you want to target all text input fields.