# Detect loss of focus in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to be able to detect when arbitrary elements loose focus in JavaScript, so I can build an in-line editing tool similar to jEdit.  I can't depend on jQuery for this library, so I need a native method for doing it.

I looked at onblur, which would seem to be the right thing but MDN has a note that suggests it may be IE specific?

> In contrast to MSIE--in which almost all kinds of elements receive the
>   blur event--almost all kinds of elements on Gecko browsers do NOT work
>   with this event.

Which elements will/wont work with this, is there a better way to detect such things?

If blur works, should the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onblur be changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529374/html-onchange-onblur-compatibility

Comment: Post some code with the problem you're having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `onfocusout` on the body element. The difference between `onblur` and `onfocusout` is that the latter bubbles up, so you don't have to install it for every node that you want.

However `onfocusout` is not cross-browser and is IE's feature, not a standard. I don't know of any problems with setting `onblur` in current browsers, except that it doesn't bubble.

The only hack to be notified whenever a blur occurs is for you to poll the `document.activeElement` and firing events when you see changes. See [Detect which form input has focus using JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354718/detect-which-form-input-has-focus-using-javascript-or-jquery/4455401#4455401)

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect the loss of focus, for accessibility audits, I personally use the ugly combination of all the following:

```js
(function($){

var focusCounter = 0;

/* Set focus outline (CSS, jQuery): */
$("*").on("focus","body",function(e){$(e.target).css("outline","5px solid orange");$(e.target).on("blur",function(e){$(e.target).css("outline","none");})});

/* Log keypress */
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
    console.log("========= KEYDOWN ", e.key, " ==================");
});

/* Log currently focused element (On start) */
console.log("CURRENT: ",document.activeElement);

/* Log focused element (On focus) */
document.addEventListener("focus",function(){
    console.log(
        "[ " + (focusCounter++).toString() + " ]",
        "FOCUSED: ",
        "<" + document.activeElement.nodeName + ">",
        ($.trim($(document.activeElement).text())? $.trim($(document.activeElement).text()) : $.trim($(document.activeElement).val())).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").substring(0, 30) + '...',
        document.activeElement
    );

},true);

/* Try to detect loss of focus (Works in Chrome) */
document.addEventListener("focusout", function(event){console.log((!event.relatedTarget)?"⚠ FOCUS LOST":"");});

/* Fallback, checks in intervals if the focus is still active/lost e.g. if onfocus or onfocusout didn't work */
(function(){setInterval(function(){console.log('interval check: ',(document.body===document.activeElement)?"FOCUS LOST":"ok");},8500);})();

})(jQuery);
```

Idea: All of those I set as a bookmarklet so I can easily access it