# Javascript: Call function every time browser loading is cancelled

Tags: javascript, python, django, loading

I hope you can help me. I need to call a javascript function every time the browser loading is cancelled. I think I may use window.stop() but I don't know how exactly read when the window stopped loading. What I'm trying to achieve is this:
[Do something when I click browser's cancell button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqzSB.png)

I can provide more information about my project, I'm developing a web app with Django (Python) to execute a Fbprophet model. But I need to achieve this with Javascript. And what I want to do with the function is hide the loading bar you can see in the picture.

I hope someone knows how to do it.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can JavaScript detect when the user stops loading the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794047/can-javascript-detect-when-the-user-stops-loading-the-document)