# Detect when an iframe starts to load new URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

How can I detect that an iframe on my page **starts** to load a new page?

Our situation is:

- When iFrame content starts to change we need to display a "loading" animation and hide the search-box.
- I know how to handle the "iframe has finished to load" event (to hide the animation) but not how to catch the initial "starting to change" event...

Note:
I can attach jquery "click" hook to the links on the menu, which will work. However, inside the iframe content there are many cross-reference links, and the "change" event also applies for them! So we need to catch event when **user clicks on a link inside the iframe** or when the **iframe src is changed via javascript** - because we also want to show the loading-animation and hide the search-box.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4010296/1427878

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found a better solution if iframe and the container page is same origin, don't have to put extra code into the inner page:

```
<iframe src="same-origin.com" onload="content_finished_loading(this)"></iframe>
<script>
    var indicator = document.querySelector('.loading-indicator');
    var content_start_loading = function() {
        indicator.style.display = 'block';
    };

    var content_finished_loading = function(iframe) {
        indicator.style.display = 'none';
        // inject the start loading handler when content finished loading
        iframe.contentWindow.onunload = content_start_loading;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive solution :) I love it!

Comment: Perfect! nice idea!

Comment: As @jbyrd mentioned in a comment below, using `iframe.contentWindow.onbeforeunload` instead of `.onunload` will trigger the callback earlier, in fact just when the new request is sent.

Comment: Note that this only works when the iframe contentWindow has the same origin as the script trying to set the event listener.

Answer (score 29):

I came up with following solution - which is only possible because we control the content of the iframe content and the host-window

Inside the iframe we add following script to the page footer (all pages use the same template, so this is a change to a single file)

```
<script>
window.onunload = function() {
    // Notify top window of the unload event
    window.top.postMessage('iframe_change', '*');
};
</script>
```

Inside the host-window we add this script to monitor the iframe state

```
function init_content_monitor() {
    var content = jQuery('.iframe');

    // The user did navigate away from the currently displayed iframe page. Show an animation
    var content_start_loading = function() {
        alert ('NOW: show the animation');
    }

    // the iframe is done loading a new page. Hide the animation again
    var content_finished_loading = function() {
        alert ('DONE: hide the animation');
    }

    // Listen to messages sent from the content iframe
    var receiveMessage = function receiveMessage(e){
        var url = window.location.href,
            url_parts = url.split("/"),
            allowed = url_parts[0] + "//" + url_parts[2];

        // Only react to messages from same domain as current document
        if (e.origin !== allowed) return;
        // Handle the message
        switch (e.data) {
            case 'iframe_change': content_start_loading(); break;
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    // This will be triggered when the iframe is completely loaded
    content.on('load', content_finished_loading);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, it helpe me. I change the window.onunload statment for this:         $(window).on('beforeunload ',function() {
            window.top.postMessage('iframe_change', '*');
        }); It was much faster for me.

Comment: In my opinion, this is overly complex, and misses the main point that the key event should be `onbeforeunload`, not `onunload`. The OP clearly states he wants to know when a frame *starts* loading a new url. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30719095/422845

Comment: will this work if URL I am loading(in iFrame) is from different domain?

Comment: @YugandharPathi yes. notice the second argument of the `postMessage` method is '*', which means the messa is posted to the top window context regardless of the domain it's hosting it. so The iframe can be hosted anywhere else.

Comment: Btw very nice solution. This helped me a lot, I also needed to know when the iframe started loading new URL, and this worked perfectly for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a possible solution at: [iFrame src change event detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429045/iframe-src-change-event-detection)

However, if you want to manipulate the target page, then it is not needed to touch the  iframe-target file content. Just add the correct JS  code in parent page and it can access SAME-ORIGIN iframe. I used something like this:

```
<iframe id="xyz" ....>
.....
<script>
var iframeElement = document.getElementById("xyz");
var iframe_El = iframeElement.contentDocument || iframeElement.contentWindow.document;
// manipulate iframe_El wih "on complete" events and like that.
....
</script>
```

more at: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnb1stc8/

Answer (score -1):

When you are creating the iframe dynamically, include the ONLOAD event like so...

```
F=document.createElement('iframe');
F.onload=function(){
    UpdateDetails(
        this.contentWindow.document.title,
        this.contentWindow.location
    );
};
F.src='some url';
document.getElementById('Some_Container').appendChild(F);
```

The onload event will now constantly update the global variables below via the function below, as the user surfs the net:

```
var The_Latest_Title='';
var The_Latest_URL='';
function UpdateDetails(Title,URL){
    The_Latest_Title=Title;
    The_Latest_URL=URL;
}
```