# iframe just before unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to capture an event which should be triggered just before the content of the iframe disappears.

I have been trying to accomplish something like this

```
$iframe = $('iframe');
$iframe.beforeunload(function () {
  debugger;
});
```

OR

```
$iframe = $('iframe');
$iframe.unload(function () {
  debugger;
});
```

I have even tried binding it to the iframe window itself without any luck

```
$iframe = $('iframe');
$iframe[0].contentWindow.onunload = function () {
  debugger;
};
```

**None of these eventhandlers actually trigger for me**

and I am quite confused why. To reload the iframe I use `.reload()` from outside the iframe and from within, maybe I need to use a different method?

Comment: How about: $iframe = $('iframe')[0];

Comment: Then: $iframe.contentWindow.onunload = function ...

Comment: Hmm, this should be the equivalence: `$iframe[0].contentWindow.onunload`

Comment: Yes, you would think, but I've seen stupider things...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Figured it out! I didn't know the `contentWindow` looses its reference after a reload.

```
$iframe.load(function () {
  $iframe[0].contentWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
    debugger;
  };
});
```

Comment: On modern versions of jQuery (3.x) you'd need to change this to `$iframe.on( 'load', function(){ ... } ); `