# How can I detect an unloaded iframe?

Tags: javascript

```js
var frame_loaded = 0;

function setFrameLoaded() {
  frame_loaded = 1;
}

$('#btn').click(function() {
  if (frame_loaded == 1) {
    console.log('iframe loaded');
  } else {
    console.log('iframe not loaded');
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">click me</button>
<iframe onload="setFrameLoaded();" src='http://www.load41.com'/></iframe>
```

Hello, I need help. How can I detect an unloaded iframe on my website? I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe just before unload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718692/iframe-just-before-unload-event)

Comment: @hgb123 I think he means "non-loaded," not "unload."

Comment: @razer have you verified that your `setFrameLoaded` function runs? E.g. by console.logging something at its beginning.

Comment: I think you can try `onerror` event so when anything wrong happens onerror fires and you can catch that.