# unblockUI after page stop is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to unblockui when stop loading page request is called.

```
dashboard: function(e,data) {
                    window.location = $("#dashboard-url").val()+"?trace_id="+data.id;
                      $.blockUI();
     }
 }
```

but before "window.location" page loads I press stop loading page in browser still UI is blocked. 
is there any method with which I can unblock ui when stop loading page request is called.?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detect when the user cancel a page loading with javascript.
See this discussion: [Detect when user clicks link, but aborts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776447/detect-when-user-clicks-link-but-aborts)

Comment: can we do it with some other technology apart from Javascript?

Comment: You can use some workaround with javascript as setting a timeout to check if the page hasn't refreshed in a reasonable time. Other tecnology means a plugin for the browser or a customized browser. The better way would be to use ajax to load the content instead of the classic window.location redirect.