# Selected text event trigger in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to **trigger a JavaScript function when someone selects a given text fragment** on a page using mouse?
Also, is there any way to **find the position of selected text** on the page?

Update:
To be more clear, text fragment  can be part of a sentence or a word or a phrase or whole a paragraph.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Update**:
In the meantime, a "*Text was selected*" (DOM) event was created and is supported by all current browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select_event

Note this  event only works on **form elements**, i.e. added to the  [`HTMLInputElement` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

---

There is no "*Text was selected*" `(DOM)` event, but you can bind a `mouseup` event to the `document.body`. Within that event handler, you might just check the

```
document.selection.createRange().text
```

or

```
window.getSelection()
```

methods. There are several topics on Stackoverflow, like this one [javascript to get paragraph of selected text in web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845390/javascript-to-get-paragraph-of-selected-text-in-web-page).

I'm not sure what you mean with "finding the position", but to stay in my example world you could use the `event propertys` for X+Y mouse positions.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/1/

Comment: Thanks Andy, Ya I think best we can get is X+Y mouse positions.

Comment: You should also consider selection via the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for comments Tim. any pointers to selection via the keyboard?

Comment: There is a "Text was selected" (DOM) event: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp

Comment: When it comes to keyboard selection, I watched for the user releasing shift:
`document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 16) highlight();
});`

Comment: The [selectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange) event is preferable because `window.getSelection()` might return old `selection` objects on `mouseup` events.

Comment: @user681814 - [Only for form controls, not other elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-select).

Comment: Updated answer: things have changed, now you can use select event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event
And also selectionchange(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange), as mentioned above

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov: **HTMLInputElement** is the key part in the links you posted. As T.J. Crowder said, these events are triggered only for form controls.

Answer (score 71):

Here's a quick mashup:

```
$('div').mouseup(function() {
    var text=getSelectedText();
    if (text!='') alert(text);
});

function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}​

<div>Here is some text</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FvnPS/11/

Comment: There seems to be a pervasive idea that `window.getSelection();` is equivalent to IE's `document.selection.createRange().text;`. Are people copying from the same, inaccurate source? Anyway, `window.getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object while `document.selection.createRange().text;` returns a string, which is a very different object. The confusion arises from the fact that the `toString` method of `Selection` object returns the selected text, meaning that `alert(window.getSelection());` will alert the selected text.

Comment: Fixed. The mozilla docs say: "This makes the selection object appear like a string, when it is really an object with its own properties and methods. Specifically, the return value of calling the toString() method of the Selection object is passed." :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection

Comment: Heh. I hadn't seen that before. Sorry to whinge on your answer: as you may have inferred, I've corrected this a few times on SO before.

Comment: @Tim Down - You weren't winging, you were in fact correct and did the right thing in pointing that out.

Comment: MDN link above is not working anymore. The new might be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Comment: Yes thanks @DerMike for an updated link, here's a link to the specific section about string representation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection#string_representation_of_the_selection_object  For anyone reading the comment now, @karim79's original answer just returned `window.getSelection();` directly; but @karim79 edited the answer to explicitly return `...getSelection().toString()`, and therefore I think he addressed @TimDown's concern, (check edit history)

Answer (score 15):

There is a new experimental API that deals with this:

The selectionchange event of the Selection API is fired when the selection object of the document is modified, or when the selection associated with an `<input>` or a `<textarea>` changes. The selectionchange event is fired at the document in the first case, on the element in the second case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange

Note that this is bleeding edge and not guaranteed to work across even major browsers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13804253)

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: The latest standard is also missing a basic "selectable" property; so a vendor prefix is still required as every browser implements it differently.  Again, this has existed in ActionScript for 2 decades since v1: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#selectable

Comment: It's worth noting that while this is still experimental, at the time of this comment, every major browser implements this, and this will work for 96.7% of web users. https://caniuse.com/?search=selectionchange

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about the mouse thing but this line works for mobile, this invoked every time a change made on the text selection -

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {

});
```

Comment: This worked on chrome

Answer (score 2):

When you press the mouse button down, the `mousedown` event is fired, when the mouse button is released, the `mouseup` and then `click` events are fired.

So we listen to the `mouseup` event and check if any text has been selected, and respective operations are performed.

```
const p = document.getElementById('interactiveText');

p.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection().toString();

  if (selection === '') {
    console.log('click');
  } else {
    console.log('selection', selection);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such event you described. But you can emulate that function.

Look over [here](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) for the code and demo.

Comment: Thanks ShiVik, it is really helpful. Does this emulation has browser dependence?

Comment: @abhishiktiwari - AFAIU the blog - none

Answer (score 1):

There is "Text was selected"  event. But only for textarea as I hava known.

```
<textarea onselect="message()" name="summary" cols="60" rows="5">
请写入个人简介，不少于200字！
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut to get the selected text from event object.

```
event.currentTarget[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it out on MDN. It's exactly what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event

The event is trigger and return the selected text when the selection is done.

If you want the selected text on every time the selection change.
There is the selectionchange event for document and html input and textarea.
Selectionchange event for document is supported on most browsers but it is supported only on Firefox for html input and textarea elements.

There is a polyfill for that which will support for all browsers.

https://github.com/channyeintun/selection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
var selectedText = "";

if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
}

if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
}

if (document.selection) {
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
}

function textSelector() {
   alert(selectedText);
}
textSelector();
```