# Execute a JavaScript function when user selects some text in an html file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an html file that displays some text. I need to call a JavaScript function when the user selects some text on it. I have the following code but the `highlightSelection()` function never gets called.

```
window.onselect = highlightSelection;

function highlightSelection() {

}
```

Is there any other way to call a JS function while user selects some text?

Comment: There is no DOM event for text selection or 'highlighting'. [Here is a link with more information][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put the text in the appropriate element, an example:

```
<input type="text" value="This is some selectable text" onselect="showMsg()" />

function showMsg(){

}
```