# How to give the SELECTED text an unique ID using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to create a serial of text sections each with an unique ID, so that I can link each section to another specified objection in my webpage. **Each text section is Selected range like this**

[image: a text section selected to be added an unique id]

I have try to use rangy library to do it.(see [Rangy In google code](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/))。But it merely can give **selected** text a class name. How to give these an Id?

Comment: Can you give us some sample input HTML and sample output HTML? For styling purposes there is no essential difference between ids and classes, and if you can set a class you can also set the id so I'm really not sure what your question is.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I have just edited

Comment: I don't upload this webpage yet. @tymeJV

Comment: Sorry do you want to id stuff that a user selects?  Or do you want to display areas of text and make them selected?

Comment: Yes, I ant to id stuff that a user selects @Papasmile

Comment: OK see that answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript .  Then if you want just copy that text into a variable or do some operations on your text directly.  Does that work?

Comment: @Papasmile , It does work, to some degree. I mean I can get text section I select, But I can give this section an id tag for further purpose.

Comment: since it is not a object it is tough to give an ID.  You could store the ID of it's container (eg div) and store start and end position of selected text, then refer to it that way later.

Answer (score 0):

Unique ID generator:

```
var uniqueClientIdCounter = 1;
function uniqueId() { 
   return "unique-client-id-" + uniqueClientIdCounter++; 
}
```

Comment: I may not  make my question clear. I want to create an id to SELECTED RANGE!!

Comment: @user1297181 You should be very attentive when writing your question. What's the problem, you don't know how to get selected text range?

Comment: Yes of course I can get selected range, But what I really want to do is to create an ID tag to it. @Andrei

Comment: Create object {start: 123, end: 234, id: "123-234"}. Should work out