# Google Analytics Goal for selecting text on web page

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a project page at http://fulldecent.github.io/cameralife/ and some users will "convert" by selecting this text on the page:

```
git clone https://github.com/fulldecent/cameralife.git
```

And hopefully they will paste this into a terminal :-)

I am looking for advice on how to fire a Google Analytics goal when this text is selected. Right now I am working with:

- Attach to `mouseup`
- Check `createRange` or `window.getSelection`
- Fire Analytics goal

That technique is at: [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)

This approach is from 2010, and wanted to ask first. Is this the best approach with HTML5 or should I be using a more modern approach?

Comment: Wouldn't the oncopy event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.oncopy) work (never used it, but looks like the way to go) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [CopyPaste by Tynt](http://www.tynt.com/product_copypaste.php#axzz2h3C6WtYK). The main purpose is different (inserting your URL to copied text), but why wouldn't it allow firing an trackEvent request, which would subsequently record a conversion (assuming you would set up goal tracking based on specific event occurrence)