# Pop up message to appear when text is highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to show a pop up message when user is trying to highlight and copy text from a paragraph. I've searched around the net for possible solutions but I could not find any that will trigger pop up message when text or random part of the paragraph is selected.

I've looked [at this](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/). But it seems that it uses div block rather than pop up.

It seems that @Nishit Maheta answer solved my issue. Shortly I will update the post with my solution.

Comment: this will help you ?http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/11/javascript-text-selection-popover.html

Comment: If you mean text selection, you can use [text selection event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "exact",
    elements: "test",
    skin: "o2k7",
    skin_variant: "red",

    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.onMouseUp.add(function (ed, e) {
            var x = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
            if(x)
              alert(x);
        });
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RvCw4/11/)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap Popover. Following is a sample code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <p  data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

**It works well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.**

```js
 $("#myDiv").mousedown(function(){
    
              $("#myDiv").mouseup(function(){
    
                         $("#myPopUp").show();
              });
    });
```

```css
#myPopUp
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
    hello please select the text and see
</div>
<div id="myPopUp">
    popover message
</div>
```

Comment: I would possibly consider it as solution, but in my case I found  Nishit Maheta solution more relevant. Otherwise with no doubts I could use your proposition.

Comment: Great, I have just seen it.. Awesome.