# javascript: show share button by selecting of text from an article

Tags: javascript, html

If a user select some text from the article of a webpage then show share and copy button for the following selected text.
I want to do something like this..
[the guardian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37feI.jpg)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp Check it

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt event for text selection but you can use

`onmouseup` this would be invoked whenever user releases his left mouse button. After every such event we can check if the user has selected any text or not

`window.getSelection()` to test for any text selection. If the selected text is not an empty string, you can invoke your function which would show up required buttons

[Here is an example with code (note - uses jQuery)](http://www.jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/1/)

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)