# Building a Chrome extension where I need to have a script be activated when the user highlights text

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Anyone know if there is a trigger for this or variable I can poll to check if something is currently highlighted on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a "mouseup"-event was fired and then get the currently selected text:

```js
document.onmouseup = ()=>{
  selection = window.getSelection().toString()
    if(selection){
      alert(`"${selection}" is highlighted`)
    }
}
```

```html
Select me!
```

(Read [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript))