# Insert HTML tag to multiple selected text from different paragraph tags in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add new HTML tags for the multi selected text from the different paragraph tag. HTML code snippet as below:

```
<div class="sampleContent">
<p>Hello</p>
<p>This one is</p>
<p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

So in above snippet I have selected "llo" text from first P tag, "This one is" text from second P tag and "Sample" text from third P tag. Now on any button selection that newly created tag should get added to all selected text so that output will be like below:

```
<div class="sampleContent">
<p>"He"<div id="1"> llo </div></p>
<p><div id="1"> This one is </div></p>
<p><div id="1"> Sample </div>Text</p>
</div>
```

So How can I add this newly created "div" element for all the selected text?

I Tried below code:

```
const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('sampleContent')[0];
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
const selection = window.getSelection();
 if (selection.rangeCount) {
 const replacement = document.createElement('div');
 replacement .setAttribute( "id", "1" );
 replacement.textContent = selection.toString();
 const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
 range.deleteContents();
 range.insertNode(replacement);
}
});
```

But it is giving output as :

```
 <div class="sampleContent">
 <p>"He"<div id="1"> llo 
 This one is
 Sample 
 </div></p>
 <p>Text</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: @antonku can you please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
        var count=0;
    const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('sampleContent')[0];
wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    count++;
    const original=event.target.textContent.toString();
const selection = window.getSelection();
 if (selection.rangeCount) {
 const replacement = document.createElement('div');
 replacement .setAttribute( "id", count );
 replacement.textContent = selection.toString();
 const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
 var array=original.split("");
 array.splice(range.startOffset,range.endOffset-range.startOffset)

 var string=array.join("");
 event.target.textContent=string;
 range.deleteContents();
 range.insertNode(replacement);

}
});
```

Basically what I did is

- Changed the event from mouseout to mouseup for more accurate results.
- I applied a counter which increments on every selection event. This counter will be your id for the div. Same id of multiple elements should not be present, because of that all your results were clubbed into one div.
- I took the whole paragraph text in a variable and removed the selected part from it and appended it back to the paragraph with the div.

Results-
[image]

Comment: what if I want to do it without using event mouseout or mouseout. I mean to say text are already selected and I need to update that tag in one go.

Comment: You cannot do it because there is no textselection event defined in the DOM.              Refer this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript

Comment: but there might be API's if you are aware which will independently gives the selection text from the particular HTML tag. Instead of using window.getSelection(), is it possible to select the text from particular tag ?

Comment: window.getSelection() is itself based on the selection api. I have no idea if other API based on this API exist. But for your question the above implementation does it. Further on selection API refer this             
               https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection_API         If you got what you were looking for upvote and mark the answer correct so it can help others too. Thank You.