# Add class on highlighted elements?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a class on highlighted elements? For example: If I Select the `.block-2, .block-3, .block-4`, and press `Enter` key then all of these blocks should add a new class. I mean I need to get all of these elements on highlight selection when pressed the `Enter` key.

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="block-1"> 1st </div>
  <div class="block-2"> 2nd </div>
  <div class="block-3"> 3rd </div>
  <div class="block-4"> 4th </div>
  <div class="block-5"> 5th </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youll want to use the selections api to do this. You can use `containsNode` to do the rest, if your are ie9+.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Assuming you can use `containsNode` you should just be able to listen to `keydown`, filter by `Enter`, and then finaly query the document for the selection and apply classes depending on if the block nodes are contained within the selection.

```
const $root = document.querySelector('.root');

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.code == "Enter") {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    console.log(selection)
    for (const $child of $root.children) {
        if (selection.containsNode($child) || $child.contains(selection.anchorNode) || $child.contains(selection.focusNode)) {
        $child.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        $child.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This code was thrown together in about 3 minutes, is sub optimal, and should be reviewed before being used. You can see it in action @ https://jsfiddle.net/z0gh7eck/2/.

Comment: I would use `if (e.key == "Enter")` because with `e.code` I wasn't able to use my keypad enter

Answer (score 0):

According to jandy's answer to [stackovweflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript). There is no event that "text was selected". But you can bind `mouseup` event to check if there was a selection then add a class.

Comment: Can you please describe more