# get the number of div which contains the particular text

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am writing some code which need to access a div which contains the particular text
following is the small portion of code i am working on:

```
var txtElem = txtdiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
txtElem[9].style.border = "2px solid blue";
```

as seen above i am accessing particular div with the index number, but now i want to add more code which can return me index of div from txtElem which contains the selected text from page

Comment: Could you show some markup please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
 var txtElem = txtdiv.getElementsByTagName("div");

 for ( var i = 0; i < txtElem.length; i++) {
    if(txtElem[i].innerHTML === "The text in the div") {
       //i is the index of the div that contains the text you searched on
       alert(i);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop trough the divs and check the contents with innerHTML

Comment: @hiteshtr , if you want to get the selection of the user you might want to look into this thread  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845390/javascript-to-get-paragraph-of-selected-text-in-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Loop through divs and use [JQuery](http://jquery.com) `.html()` to check the html content of the div element.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use you may want to use jquery see http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: but this method will not return the index of my div stored in txtElem

Comment: But you have a reference to the node if you store it in a var so you can add your css to that .css method Not suitable??