# How can I know when the user selects a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, onselect

I want to perform an action when the user selects any text at the page. I tried something like this:

```
 var selObj;

       document.querySelector("p").onselect = function(){
       selObj = window.getSelection(); 
       var selectedText = selObj.toString();
       //action
```

But then I discovered that `onselect` is only for inputs and text areas, and found no other way of trying something like this.

EDIT:I know how to get the selected text, I need an event that is triggered when  the text is selected!

Comment: onfocus would probably do it

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: Not a duplicate. Linked question is how to select text. This question is how to fire an event when the user selects text.

Comment: It`s not a duplicate. The other question tells how to automatically select a text when an event occurs. This one is how to know when a text is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a mouseup event to the paragraph("p") tag. Within that event handler, you can check:

```
document.selection.createRange().text
```

or

```
window.getSelection()
```

Also, you can check here 
[javascript to get paragraph of selected text in web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845390/javascript-to-get-paragraph-of-selected-text-in-web-page).

Answer (score 0):

Use mouse events to capture the selection.

```js
var paras = document.getElementsByClassName("para");

for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
  paras[i].addEventListener('click', getSelected, false);
}

function selectElementContents(el) {

  return document.getSelection()||window.getSelection();

}

function getSelected() {

  var el = document.getElementById("selectedPara");
  alert(selectElementContents(el));

};
```

```html
<p class="para">select me</p>
<p class="para">over me</p>
<p class="para">hey here</p>
```

Comment: And if i want it to apply to any paragraph, and not one with a specific ID?